# How to block certain IP/MAC Address that access your WiFi Network ?

Tags: network, security, airport

I can see people access into my Wifi by going into AirportUtility
Here is a list of people that are connected to Wifi at the moment.

There're 2 of them in there that I'm not sure - how they get in there ?

[image]

### Goals

- I would like to both of them out.
- I also want to block a certain MAC Address for future access.

### What I have tried

I've been playing around with the AirPort Utility, and all I can do is restrict the time access to a certain MAC address.

I also came across an app called [Little Snitch](http://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/index.html), but that not exactly what I want.

Is there any Mac App that let me block/allow a certain IP address ?

Comment: what version is your AirPort running?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On your airport extreme you can block certain mac address for good with "No Access".

In your airports configuration go to the "Network" tab and check "Enable Access Control", then click on "Timed Access Control".

[image]

Then on the top add the mac address you want to prohibit and give it a description.  Towards the bottom, On the "Wireless Access Time" drop down select "No Access" and save.

[image]

Confirmed this works on a 5th generation airport running version 7.6.4

Answer (score 1):

to easily disallow any or all others from accessing your network, change your network password in Airport Utility. there's no need to block or allow IPs or MAC addresses IF there's trust for those with password access.

1. open AU
2. select your primary device
3. it should open a new window with the Base Station tab selected by default
4. enter or change password
5. notify others of the change, login with qualified devices

you can also create a guest network with separate password if you wish via the Guest tab. Good luck!

Answer (score -3):

I'm not sure of any Mac programs, but try calling up your ISP (Internet Service Provider) and they might be able to block those devices. It's worth a shot.